# Play flv locally

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, streaming, flex4.5

Is it possible to play locally saved flv file like mp3 using the Sound class in AS3?

Or in any case I have to use NetStream object and NetConnection.

Comment: How would a sound object play a video? Of course you need to use NetStream and NetConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to use `NetStream` anyway
however you'll need just `netConnection.connect(null);` before passing it to a `NetStream` constructor (like [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#includeExamplesSummary) but with local/relative path)